# Pass an argument in jQuery function using div class

Tags: jquery

I want to pass an argument to the `source` property of the jQuery function. However I am not sure how can I do that?

```js
window.onInstaShowReady = function() {
  $('.my-instashow').instaShow({
    api: '/instashow/api/',
    source: '@muradosmann', // this value
    width: 'auto',
    height: '500px',
    columns: 5,
    rows: 3,
    direction: 'vertical',
    lang: 'en',
    popupInfo: ''
  });
};
```

```html
<div class="my-instashow"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For this to work you need a reference to the `.my-instashow` element. The simplest way to do that is to select it again, or you could do it in an extensible way and loop through all of them so your code can be kept DRY:

```
<div class="my-instashow" data-source="@muradosmann"></div>
```

```js
window.onInstaShowReady = function() {
  $('.my-instashow').each(function() {
    $(this).instaShow({
      api: '/instashow/api/',
      source: $(this).data('source'),
      width: 'auto',
      height: '500px',
      columns: 5,
      rows: 3,
      direction: 'vertical',
      lang: 'en',
      popupInfo: ''
    });
  });
};
```